# How to arrange the data for bar chart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, data-visualization

I am not expert in R.
I have continuous data between 0 and 100. I do not know how to arrange the csv file to have the following bar chart
[image]

each colour shows the method, and each group of columns shows the time-points

I have created the following table, however, it seems it is not correct

[image]

How should I arrange the table in csv file and what is the R commands to create such a bar plot?

Comment: There are several implementations, but the default is [`barplot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.3/topics/barplot). If you read the documentation at that link (and available with `?barplot`), there is an "Examples" section that walks through shaping the data and calling the function. If you pay attention to the data as you plot it, you will see good examples of what your data above can look like to actually plot it. **Note**: `barplot` has changed significantly between R-3.5 and R-3.6, make sure you look at the right page/help.

Comment: (I tried the `barplot` example code from the R-3.6 help page and it did not work.)

Answer (score 1):

You can have the csv as a table. After you read to R you can use `tidyr` to manipulate it and `ggplot2` to plot it:

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_csv("filename.csv")
gather(tbl, key="Q", value="value", -Method) %>% ggplot(aes(Q, value, fill=Method) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: Thanks, it showing an error `Error: could not find function "%>%"` when it reaches to the last line

Comment: Do you have tidyverse loaded? The "pipe" should work. What R version do you use?